# Font causes GDI leak in custom control

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, gdi, resource-leak

I have created a custom control like below.

```
public partial class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
  public TextBoxEx()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    Font = Utility.normalFont;
  }

   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   {
    base.OnPaint(pe);
   }
 }
//A utility class to initialize font.   
class Utility
{

    internal static Font normalFont = new Font("Arial", 18);
}
```

I have two forms Form1 and Form2. This TextBoxEx is added to Form2. I am showing Form2 when clicking a button in Form1.

Continuously showing and closing Form2 causes GDI leak in my application. After analysing with a GDI detection tool(Bear.exe), it is found that the Font causes GDI leak.

My question is,

1. Why the Font is not released even though Dispose() method of TextBoxEx is get called.(While closing Form2, Dispose() method of TextBoxEx will be invoked automatically).
2. How can I solve GDI leak caused by Font?. 
   (Font.Dispose() cannot be called in Dispose() method of TextBoxEx. Because it throws "Parameter is not valid" exception in the constructor).

Comment: Font should not be released because it is referenced in the static normalFont variable. I don't think this is a leak at all..

Comment: @Alex: When I comment this line of code "Font = Utility.normalFont;",the leak disappears. I think the Font keeps a copy not a reference. I could solve GD leak by setting Font=null in Dispose() method of TextBoxEx. But is it a good idea?

Comment: Font is reference type, so it is not copied. I think that your leaks analyzer gives incorrect information. Read Hans Passant's answer, you will not find a better expert anywhere :)

Comment: @Alex: But when I set Font=null in Dispose() method of TextBoxEx, GDI leak disappears. I have checked with TaskManager.

Comment: Interesting. Anyway, setting font to NULL in Dispose is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most drawing objects are *very* cheap to create.  A pen or a brush for example doesn't take more than a microsecond to create.  Which is why you should *always* create them when you starting drawing and dispose them when you're done drawing.  The *using* statement strongly encourages you to do so.

The Font class is difficult however.  They are *not* cheap to create, Windows needs to do a lot of work to map the font you ask for to the available set of fonts and load the TrueType outline.  Winforms has a solution for that, it **caches** fonts.  You'll incur the cost of creating the font the very first time you use it.  But you can then dispose it but the font object stays around in the font cache.  The next time you create the same font, you'll get the very cheap copy from the cache.

This is also a problem in WPF, much more so since it has much richer font support that includes support for OpenType outlines.  It was solved a different way, WPF uses an entirely separate process to cache fonts.  Acting like a font cache server for any WPF app.  You'll see this process back in Task Manager, it is the PresentationFontCache.exe process.

Anyhoo, any kind of leak diagnostic program is going to be confused by this cache.  It will think that your app is leaking fonts, it sees the fonts that are stored in the cache.  You only have a real leak when the number of used fonts grows without bounds and eventually cases your program to crash.  Easy to test, the quota that Windows imposes is low, a process cannot create more than 10,000 drawing objects.  So you don't need to run your test program for very long to reach that quota if you have a real leak.  You can also see this back in Task Manager.  View + Select Columns, tick the GDI Objects checkbox.  Ensure the number for your test program is stable and doesn't go over a couple of hundred, give or take.

Comment: When I continuously open and close the Form, GDI count in TaskManager keeps increasing by 1. But when I set Font=null in Dispose() method of TextBoxEx, GDI leak disappears. Is it recommended to set Font as NULL in Dispose() method of TextBox control?

Comment: When I continuously open and close Form2, GDI count in TaskManager keeps increasing by 1. After increasing the GDI count to some count (70-80), it will automatically decreases to some count and so on.
When I add 500 TextBoxEx to form2 and continuously open and close the Form, GDI count in TaskManager will be 504. It is not increasing.
when setting Font=null in Dispose() method of TextBoxEx,GDI count in TaskManagerwill be reset to 4 while closing the Form. Is it recommended to set Font as NULL in Dispose() method of TextBox control Or Should I ignore it and trust GC to collect the GDI objects?

Comment: I do see something similar, odd.  It however never explodes, the GDI object count keeps going down and back up without having to do anything in the Dispose() method or setting the font reference back to null.  I'll do some more digging when I have time, but you certainly don't have a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I am disposing all other drawing objects(Pen,Brush,Bitmap etc), I have decided to leave control's Font object and let GC to collect it. Any way I will keep watching this thread and Kindly do post if you see any thing interesting.